# Call custom function when Django rest-auth/register succeeds

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is there an easy way to tap into a successful call to the Django REST Framework /rest-auth/register API call (Django-rest-auth) so that a custom function can be called when a user has been successfully registered? The custom function I have written sends a push notification to my phone every time a user signs up.

Obviously I can edit the rest-auth code plugin but this edit would not last if I update the plugin to a newer version.

Comment: Are you using `django-rest-auth` ?

Comment: Yes. django-rest-auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two options,

1. Create your own `RegisterSerializer`, write your custom functionality and set this serializer as your Register serializer by mentioning in settings as follows so that your changes remains when you update the library.

   ```
   REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
       'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'path.to.custom.RegisterSerializer',
       ...
   }
   ```

   [Reference](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)
2. You can create `post_save` signal for User model and do your custom functionality everytime when a new user object is added.
   [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save)

Comment: Option 2 looks like exactly what I want thanks. Where would you recommend putting the post_save listener? Can it go in a view.py file for example?

Comment: Glad it helped :) I would suggest to create a separate signals.py file and write all the signals there :)

Comment: Do I have to do something to get the signals.py file included?

Comment: Yes. You have to import your signals file in your Appconfig ready method. There is an example here in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/#django.dispatch.receiver). Check out the `Where should this code live?` part :)